# Passing options to curl when using git push

Tags: git, curl

As I understand, git relies on curl when doing http transfers (at least when using http, I'm sure ssh is different).

Given this, is there a way to make git pass specific flags to curl? e.g. I'd like to pass something like --limit-rate 100k to test a git push command under throttled conditions. Is this possible?

Comment: I've just looked over the source code of git. Unfortunately, it seems almost impossible to do that in a regular way. `--limit-rate` option apparently corresponds to CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE option in libcurl's C API, but the CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE option is not used in the source code of git.

Comment: @TaizoIto: Thanks for taking the time to look through the sources! If it can't be done, so be it :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer to your specific question, but it can help you to get the same results.

You can use [netbrake](http://www.hping.org/netbrake/), for instance:

```
$ netbrake --limit 100k git push
```

The benefit of `netbrake` is that you can use it with any other command.  The downside is that is Linux specific.

Another alternative, is to set a environment variable.  I am not sure if git honour those variable (although other programs do).  Check the [connection options for Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTLOWSPEEDLIMIT).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this on Mac or Windows. :( I'll play around with the env variable, though the one you point to (CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT) seems to have a different semantic. CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE is the one that seems to match the --limit-rate semantic.

Comment: I pointed that one because was the first among the connection options :-)  The environment variable should work in Mac, you can always try `$ CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=100k git push...`.  That might not work on Windows, though.

Comment: Strangely, I couldn't get this to work on the Mac even when using curl directly (no git). e.g. `CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=10k curl ...` and my upload speed is still super high. I also tried running `export CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE=10k` before curl, with no luck.